# SSRS Report: Pass parent report multi-value parameters to child report but not use them

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, back-button

I am trying to create a back to parent report button from a drill-through report without using the javascript:history.back(-1) method as this only works in IE and I need it to work in Edge&Chrome.

My parent report has a multi-list parameter of timekeepers (among others), which has a sub report showing the timekeepers selected. This list drills through to a report for each individual timekeeper depending on which name you click, and I need to be able to get back to the parent report but with all of the timekeeper parameters used to run the initial report, rather than the individual timekeeper in the drill through.

Is there maybe a way to pass through the parent parameters to the drill-through report so can be passed back with the back button, but not actually use them to filter the data?

Answer (score 0):

Create parameters in the sub-report, and pass the values to them. You don't have to do anything with the parameters in the sub-report - they can just hold the values till you need them.

Comment: Thanks all sorted - I was being completely thick and thought adding an additional parameter would filter my drill-through reports results, which it obviously doesn't... my bad but thanks for your answer anyway.

Comment: @user7414114 No problem